# How to show different error messages to different http errors in the angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angular2-observables

I've added the code below. Basically I want to show error messages to different scenarios(HTTP status codes are returned). I'm trying to grasp all these concepts about observables etc but so far I've not reached anywhere. Hope someone could help me on this.

```
export class HomePage {

  private formData: FormGroup;
  public errors: string = "";

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public authService: AuthServiceProvider,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder                                                                                                                                                                                 
    ) {

    this.formData = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.email])],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
    });


    doRegister(){
      this.authService.register(this.formData.value)
      //Coming from angular 1 and I've honestly have no idea what I'm doing from here
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => this.navCtrl.push(ProfiePage,data))
      .catch((error: any) => {
          /*

          I want to show different msgs for different http erros
          example 
          for 500 "username already exists"
          for 400 " Invalid username"
          for 401 "Someother error"
          How do I do this?

          */
          this.errors = "Username already exists";
      });

    }


  }

}

@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider {


  register(userData): Observable<UserModel[]>{
      // http error 500 will be return if there is an email exists error
      return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl+this.config.user.register,JSON.stringify(userData))
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());

  }



}





<ion-content padding id="page2">

/* I want to show the errors here */
{{error}}

  <form [formGroup]="formData" (ngSubmit)="register()">
    <ion-list id="signup-list1">
      <ion-item id="signup-input5">
        <ion-label>
          Email
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input type="email" placeholder="" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item id="signup-input6">
        <ion-label>
          Password
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button [disabled]="!formData.valid" ion-button color="positive" block>
      Sign up
    </button>
  </form>


</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the error object in the catch block there will be a status property so you can access the http error code as error.status. By checking this error.status value using if conditions you can handle your scenario. But looking at your code it seems you are creating validation messages from the error code. I think it would be better to return validation messages from server (if you can edit the API) rather than manipulating it in the code. So if you want to change the validation message in future you can do it without any client code changes.

Answer (score 0):

> You can throw error from service, and get in component

```
register(userData): Observable<UserModel[]>{
  return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl+this.config.user.register,
         JSON.stringify(userData))
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch(
        (error: Response) => {
            return Observable.throw(error.json() as JsonResponse)
        });;
}
```

And in Component you can

```
test(): void {
    this.testService.register().subscribe(
        (data: UserModel[]) => {
            console.log(data);
        }, (error: JsonResponse) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    )
}
```